# Как убрать ограничение скорости объектов в Box2d?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, box2d, libgdx

Я пишу игру на Java c использованием libGDX. Тела должны свободно перемещаться в пространстве под действием сил гравитации, однако возникает такая проблема: скорость тел не превышает порядка 120 м/с. То есть получается, что тела не разгоняются и их скорость равна 120 м/с. Выглядит очень неестественно, хотелось бы как-нибудь с этим побороться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорость объектов ограничена, чтобы вычисления не приводили к слишком большим погрешностям. У вас два пути:

1. Изменить максимальную скорость `MaxTranslation` в настройках со значения по умолчанию `2.0` на большее.
2. Уменьшить масштаб объектов, выполнить вычисления, увеличить масштаб. Это рекомендуемый способ.

Вычисления производятся с помощью чисел с плавающей точкой. Если у вас слишком большой разброс по размерам и скоростям, то вся модель полетит к чёрту из-за нарастающей как снежный ком погрешности.

Comment: Спасибо. Уменьшил масштаб в 20 раз, теперь более менее играбельно стало.